# SQLite as Android storage?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing android apps, yet I used shared-pref and JSON(rest web service) for storing data. I generally tend to prefer less sophisticated technologies, as I believe more complexity results in more issues. But for my new app, it may be better to have db-like storage.

What do you think about using SQLite in Android , is it really light? Have you experienced performance or compatibility issues developing SQLite for Android?

Namely would you recommend SQLite over simpler alternatives as android storage solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is light, fast and it works.

It all depends on what data you want to save. If it is good to have a real database with relationships for your new app, then don't be afraid and go into SQLite.

Comment: I'd add that the versions of SQLite that ships with some versions of Android have relationships but don't enforce them.

Comment: @Blrfl it does since Android 2.2 - see http://www.simpligility.com/2010/08/referential-integrity-with-sqlite-on-android-the-lazy-way/

Comment: I'm still supporting apps that have to run on earlier versions, so it's still a concern.